# How do I integrate Auth0 with my Supersonic (Appgyver) hybrid app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, auth0, supersonic

I'm attempting to build my first hybrid mobile app using [Supersonic](https://www.appgyver.com/). I want to use [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) to handle the app login feature.

How can I accomplish this?

It seems there could (and should) be a way to do this given Auth0's support for Cordova, Phonegap, and Ionic.

I'm using Supersonic's default AngularJS framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can just follow the Ionic guide since it'll work for SuperSonic (Cordova + Angular = Ionic || Supersonic :)).

https://auth0.com/docs/native-platforms/ionic

Did it not work in any way?

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've been tinkering with the Ionic and Cordova guides. I'm new to AngularJS but I think I'm getting close. :)